# PHP_comparison days between 2date

Tags: php

i write code in php and i get all days between 2date

```
function getDatesBetween2Dates($startTime, $endTime){    
    $day = 86400;  
    $format = 'Y-m-d';  
    $startTime = strtotime($startTime);  
    $endTime = strtotime($endTime);  
    $numDays = round(($endTime - $startTime) / $day) + 1;  
    $days = array();  
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numDays; $i++) {  
        $days[] = date($format, ($startTime + ($i * $day)));  
    }  
    return $days;  
}  
$days = getDatesBetween2Dates($_POST['periodfrom'], $_POST['periodto']);  
foreach($days as $key => $value){  
    echo $daydatey = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));    
    //contain days between 2date from my form
}   
$days2 = getDatesBetween2Dates($ppfr, $ppto);  
foreach($days2 as $key2 => $value2){  
    echo $daydatey2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value2));  
}
```

Contain days between 2date from my DB
I just need to make comparison between $days and $days2  to check if any days in(`$days`)  exist or equal or like days in (`$days2`) just that. Please help.

Comment: If the dates come from your DB, can't you use native functions from your DB to do these comparisons ?

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you user1562744

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at DateTime::diff / date_diff..

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php (OOP)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php (Procedural)

This does however require php 5.3+ so ignore this answer if you are below that.

Example:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Comment: so  mobile sucks .... when started no answer .... than get call and when submitted there is an answer before 9 minute my ... +1 and remove my answer

Comment: NP :) Few times I wrote up an answer and forgot to hit the add answer button, only to do it 30 minutes later :)